# Instagram 400 Spammy Request

Tags: php, real-time, instagram, instagram-api

I currently have an app that I use to track Instagram hastags and user posts, and keywords. I have the appropriate tokens back from Instagram to make calls to the API. Specifically I am having trouble tracking new Instagram hashtags once I have an authenticated user.

I am attempting to create a real-time API subscription (https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/). To do this I am using guzzle and with a laravel backend to build up the request. I build my request similar to the below....

```
       $data = [
            'client_id' => $instagram['client_id'],
            'client_secret' => $instagram['client_secret'],
            'object' => 'tag',
            'object_id' => 'testterm',
            'aspect' => 'media',
            'verify_token' => \Str::random(10),
            'callback_url' => "maycallbackURL"
        ];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post('https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/',['body' => $data]);
```

This fails with

```
400 BAD REQUEST
```

My callback URL supports both a GET and POST per Instagram requirements. I've checked my X-Ratelimit-Remaining and it is says around 4990 remaining, so its not rate limiting. When I curl the same request from the server I get a 400 error code and....

```
unable to reach callback url
```

Locally I have the app running through a secure tunnel to make the endpoint accessible to the Instagram callback, and this works, allowing me to subscribe and unsubscribe as I please. This is part of the reason I'm very confused why this isn't working on my server.

I assume this relates to the part of the Instagram documentation that says

"You may also receive responses with an HTTP response code of 400 (Bad Request) if we detect spammy behavior by a person using your app. These errors are unrelated to rate limiting."

I am curious if somehow it thinks my requests are SPAM and if anyone knows any tips to be sure of this

** THERE ARE ALOT OF POSTS THAT RELATE TO THIS BUT MOST SAY ITS AN ISSUE THAT RESOLVED ITSELF ON INSTAGRAM ABOUT A YEAR BACK...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have entered a bad value for 'callback_url'. This should be an accessible URL for the API to post your data back to. In other words, the location of your script.

Replacing 'maycallbackURL' with the endpoint of your script should solve the problem.

Comment: the 'maycallbackurl' is actually a place holder. I have a valid callback there, the fact that it hits it every so often means that unfortunately that is not the issue.